# Is there a difference in max alcohol allowed to take to US between personal use and marketing use?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, alcohol, import-taxes

I'm planing to fly to the US for some meetings with local alcohol distributors.
I need to bring with me about 10 beer brands from China 25-30 bottles each (the last leg of my flight will be China-US).

That's a total of about 250-300 bottles.

I am willing to pay the "extra fees" on the flight, if needed, but is there a way to do that or I need to go thru the usual importing process?

Is there some way in between? Something like "exhibition use" or "samples import" that can shorten the process?

Comment: You might start researching here: http://www.ttb.gov/itd/importing_alcohol.shtml

Comment: There's no way you can carry that much beer as luggage, right? So you're going to have to ship it, and your shipper should have advice (or possibly restrictions of their own).

Comment: This is what you're looking for: http://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/icp066_3.pdf  This is probably more off-topic here.

Comment: @Karlson seems to have the info. Given the quantities you're talking about, it looks like you'll need to import them normally;  there's too many bottles for the duty-free exemption to imply, and if you temporarily import them under bond, you have to take them back out of the country (i.e., nobody can consume them.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about importing large quantities of alcohol, way more than any regular traveler would usually bring.

Comment: didnt know that this forum only for leisure travelers??

Comment: I believe there is a difference but probably not the one you hoped for. The limit for marketing use would be 0, the simplified procedure only applies for personal use and “[A gift of beverage alcohol products connected with the solicitation of orders for (or the sale of) such products is considered to be for commercial use and may only be conducted by a federally licensed importer.](http://www.ttb.gov/importers/personal_importation.shtml)” So no shortcuts here.

Comment: @Sumansharma - It is not. But your question is not about travel. It is more about business imports of goods into the US. While there is a connection to travel, the question how to write a certain computer program *while travelling* would also have a connection to travel in the same manner as your question. Import rules&regulations for business may be more on topic on other stackexchange pages, such as "law.stackexchange.com".

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a difference, as stated by the [Alcohol and Tobacco Tax and Trade Bureau](http://www.ttb.gov/importers/personal_importation.shtml):

> Personal Importation of Beverage Alcohol Products
>
> ...
>
> **A gift of beverage alcohol products connected with the solicitation of
>   orders for (or the sale of) such products is considered to be for
>   commercial use and may only be conducted by a federally licensed
>   importer.**

Therefore there's no "tax free" limit and you must do the import through a licensed importer, rather than on a regular flight.